# SIM lock question

Tags: updates, rooting, sim-unlocking, lg-g2, radio-firmware

I intend to buy a new sim-unlocked at&t LG G2. So I want to know is there a possibility that an update will ever relock it again? Am I free to root it and install custom roms without relock concerns?

And could someone please explain to me the whole "Baseband processor" thing? Doesn't an official system update always install a new baseband version (firmware ) automatically ? And can this relock the phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Is it factory SIM-unlocked, has it been unlocked through official channels, or has it been hack-unlocked?

If it's either of the first two, you should be fine through any software updates. If it's been hacked unlocked though, I'd be careful of updates until someone confirms it working.

Comment: Thanks bro but how can I know the used unlock method ?and can you explain to me what's the partition where the "simlock " issue is placed (since we can't hack some  partitions such as radio or efs )?

Comment: The only way you can really know, feasibly, is by asking the person you're getting it from. It's usually a radio partition related change.

Answer (score -1):

Once a device is unlocked from its carrier no update will re-lock your device. It is permanently unlocked.